# flatten json with logstash ruby

Tags: json, ruby, logstash

I have a json log that expands to this:

```
JSON:
 |-host : hostname
 |-httpRequest
   |-httpVersion : HTTP/1.1
   |-headers
     |-0
       |-name: X-Forwarded-For
       |-value: 1.1.1.1
     |-1
       |-name: X-Forwarded-Prot
       |-value: https
     |-2
       |-name: X-Forwarded-Port
       |-value: 443
   |-httpMethod: post
 |-action: allow
```

etc..

I would like to reformat it like this:

```
JSON:
 |-host : hostname
 |-httpRequest
   |-httpVersion : HTTP/1.1
   |-headers
     |-X-Forwarded-For : 1.1.1.1
     |-X-Forwarded-Prot : https
     |-X-Forwarded-Port : 443
   |-httpMethod: post
 |-action: allow
```

Split will just take the last [#] name/value as it overwrites the previous.
I am pretty sure this will need a ruby code block, but I haven't had luck following along with ruby code I have found online for similar scenarios.

I think the main issue here/difference with other article/answers is that it's not just a pure flatten. But need to rearrange the name:value a bit as well.

Comment: I do not have the energy to rewrite this as an answer right now, but the ruby filter needed to do this can be found [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/solved-split-filter-question-a-k-a-flatten-json-sub-array/130481/12?u=badger).

Comment: Thanks. I posted another one to this thread that worked, but will check this one out as well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick as well:

Newfield

```
    ruby {

        code => '

            event.get("[@metadata][json][httpRequest][headers]").each do |header|

                event.set("[newfield][#{header["name"]}]", header["value"])

            end

        '

    }
```

Same field

```
    ruby {

        code => '

            headerHash = {}

            event.get("[@metadata][json][httpRequest][headers]").each do |header|

                headerHash[header["name"]] = header["value"]

            end

            event.set("[@metadata][json][httpRequest][headers]", headerHash)

        '

    }
```